# I can't figure it out why it doesn't print after the line of code ( if 6 <= n <= 20 )

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I am running this code . and when i put the input as 6 or greater it dosent print anything and also dont show any error . like it doesnt print anything on and after that if 6 <= n <= 20

i tried rewritng the code or bugs and i checked it througly many times .

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys



if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    if n%2 == 0 :
        if 2 <= n <= 5:
            print("Not Weird")
    elif n%2 == 0:
        if 6 <= n <= 20 :
            print("Weird")
    elif n%2 == 0:
        if n > 20:
             print("Not Weird")
    else:
        print("Weird")
```

It doesnt show any error

Comment: If you go into `if n%2==0` then you skip all the `elif`s. That's the `else` part of `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using using `if` properly. Check this,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    if n%2 == 0 :
        if 2 <= n and n <= 5:
            print("Not Weird")

        elif 6 <= n and n <= 20 :
            print("Weird")
        elif n > 20:
             print("Not Weird")
    else:
        print("Weird")
```

**What is the mistake in your code?**

**ANS:**

```
if n%2 == 0: 
    some condition
elif n%2 ==0:
    some condition
```

Your both `if` and `elif` conditions are same. So, it never execute `elif` condition.

So, in your case when `n=6`, it goes into 1st `if` condition. As there is no any else statement in your 1st if condition. It won't `print` anything as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    if n%2 == 0 :
        if 2 <= n <= 5:
            print("Not Weird")
        elif 6 <= n <= 20 :
            print("Weird")
        elif n > 20:
             print("Not Weird")
    else:
        print("Weird")
```